# Can i buy a private key and add it to my watch-only wallet

Tags: watch-only

I have a watch only wallet i was given the address for can i buy a private key and add it to the watch only wallet

Comment: This sounds like a scam. There is no guarantee that whomever gave you the watch-only wallet even *has* the private key for it.

Comment: Yes i am very suspicious myself

Comment: I dont think you need the private key to create a watch-only wallet

Comment: No, but you cannot access funds with a watch-only wallet; as the name says, it is only for watching. You should not assume anyone has the ability to give you access to those funds.

Comment: Pieter i totally understand that, i cannot spend or even transfer anything from a watch only wallet, that is why i was even asking if it is ever possible to changes its state from watch-only to a normal wallet that can transfer or spend its contents.

Comment: If you have the private key(s), you don't need the watch-only wallet anymore; you can just create a new wallet that has access to the funds through the private key material directly. Having the watch-only wallet to begin with doesn't help with that. But again, you should assume this is a scam (I understand you're suspicious already, but let me be 100% clear: if someone offers to sell you private keys, they are scamming you; if they had the keys they'd be taking the funds themselves).

Comment: Exactly my point, it is not going to happen.